# Expected value of $\max(a, b)$

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

What is the expected value of $\max(a, b)$ where $a, b$ are uniformly distributed from $[0,1]$?

> My intuition for this question was to say $E[a] = 0.5$. This means there is probability $0.5$ that $b > a$. If $b > a$ we can say $E[b] = 0.75$ where $b$ would now be the max. Given this, my calculation for $\max(a, b)$ is $0.5(0.5) + 0.5(0.75) = 0.625$, but this does not appear to be the correct answer. Why is this approach wrong?

Comment: You also need to consider what happens in the cases $b>a$ or $b<a$ when $a\not=0.5$, and that $b>a$ is more likely when $a$ is small, while $b<a$ is more likely when $a$ is large

Comment: In short: $\mathsf E(a \mid a>b) ~{\large\gneq}~ \mathsf E(a)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My intuition for this question was to say E[a]=0.5. This means there is probability 0.5 that b>a.

Yes...ish.  It is by symmetry that we may say:  $\mathsf P(a>b)=\mathsf P(b>a)$ when the variables are independent and identically distributed.

> If b>a we can say E[b]=0.75 where b would now be the max. Given this, my calculation for max(a,b) is 0.5(0.5)+0.5(0.75)=0.625, but this does not appear to be the correct answer. Why is this approach wrong?

Well, now, by the Law of Total Expectation we do have:

$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf E(\max(a,b)) &=\mathsf E(a\mid a>b)~\mathsf P(a>b)+\mathsf E(b\mid a\leqslant b)~\mathsf P(a\leqslant b)\\&=\tfrac 12\big(\mathsf E(a\mid a>b)+\mathsf E(b\mid b \geqslant a)\big)\end{align}$

**However,** we would not expect the conditional value of $a$ to be $1/2$ *when given* $a>b$.  Indeed, knowing that $a>b$ should *raise our expectations* for $a$.

$\qquad\mathsf E(a\mid a>b)\gneq \mathsf E(a)$

Likewise we **cannot** say $\mathsf E(b\mid b>a)=0.75$.   Rather it is that $\mathsf E(b\mid b>0.5)=0.75$, which is not the same thing at all.

Indeed, by the symmetry of the random variables:

$\qquad\mathsf E(a\mid a>b)=\mathsf E(b\mid b>a)$

---

How do we figure how much to raise our expectation under the condition of largeness?  Integration is one way.

$\displaystyle\qquad\mathsf E(a\mid{a>b}) = \dfrac{\int_0^1\int_0^a a\, \mathrm d b\,\mathrm d a}{\mathsf P(a>b)}$

---

**Intuitively**

Consider the expected placement for the maximum and minimum of $a,b$ on the $[0,1]$ interval.   By symmetry and unbiasedness of the uniform distributions, these points should be expected to partition the interval into three equal segments.

So...